# Hadoop: How does NameNode know which blocks correspond to a file?

Tags: hadoop

NameNode in hadoop does not store the block information. It is kept in-memory and on startup DataNodes report the block information.

If I copyFromLocal a file to hdfs, it is transferred to hdfs, because I can see with "hadoop fs -ls".

I was wondering how Hadoop knows which filename correspond to which blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NameNode maintains a `File System Image` which stores the mapping between files -> blocks. It also stores an `edit log` which maintains any edits to the File System. The Secondary namenode periodically reads the File System Image and the Edit Log from the Namenode, and combines them to create the new File System Image for the NameNode.

Comment: This is confusing. In the documnetation it says it does not store any block information, but so File System Image is a mapping from files to blocks? So is it block ID?

Comment: Ok, this paper has a good description: 
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.18.0/hdfs_design.pdf

Comment: Check out Page 9 - Section 6 `The Persistence of File System Metadata` from the above link. It explains the concepts you're confused about. It's true that the NameNode does not store the actual blocks itself. The blocks are stored by the datanode. However, the NameNode does store the mapping between Files -> blocks.

Comment: It would be useful to point to the data structure in the actual code for such questions on top of diagrams